# How to enable/disable "function" (if ... els)

Tags: vim

I have the following keymaps:

`nnoremap <silent> <leader>vn :call Number()<CR>`

```
function! Number()
  set number relativenumber
  augroup numbertoggle
    autocmd!
    autocmd BufEnter,FocusGained,InsertLeave * set relativenumber
    autocmd BufLeave,FocusLost,InsertEnter   * set norelativenumber
  augroup END
endfunction
```

`nnoremap <silent> <leader>vN :call NoNumber()<CR>`

```
function! NoNumber()
  set number! norelativenumber
  augroup numbertoggle
    autocmd!
    autocmd BufEnter,FocusGained,InsertLeave * set norelativenumber
    autocmd BufLeave,FocusLost,InsertEnter   * set norelativenumber
  augroup END
endfunction
```

But I would like to use only one `<leader>vn` shortcut for this; i.e. to call *NoNumber* if *Number* has already been called. What is the correct way to do this?
It seems like I can use `if ... else` in Number function, but I'm not sure how to implement it correctly. Or is there some other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check if the option `number` is set:

```
if &number
    set nonumber
else
    set number
endif
```

See the [docs](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#expr-option) on using `&option`.

You can combine `if` with the mapping:

```
:nnoremap <silent> <leader>vn :if &number | call NoNumber() | else | call Number() | endif<CR>
```